# How do I merge cells of the same column in LyX?

Tags: layout, latex, lyx, subfigure

I have 3 subfigures I want to arrange so that 1 will be in the left and 2 will be in the right (one above the other):

> Figure 1  | Figure 2
>
> Figure 1 | Figure 3

Figure 1 should appear only once of course - across the entire column.

I thought I should use 2x2 table to arrange them, but I can't find a way to merge the two cells in the same column to one cell in order to put figure 1 there.

How can I merge the two cells in the same column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the multirow package. Add the package, and use something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\multirow{2}{*}{<figure 1>} & <figure 2> \\
& <figure 3>
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in directly in LyX? Without editing the LaTeX?

Comment: According to the LyX wiki (http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables#toc3), LyX can do multicolumn formatting, but not multirow, so you're pretty much stuck just working with the LaTeX source.

Comment: +1, but "pretty much stuck just working with the LaTeX source" suggests abandoning Lyx: you can enter Tex code into Lyx per my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863704/how-do-i-merge-cells-of-the-same-column-in-lyx/2896906#2896906

Answer (score 1):

You can enter Latex code snippets directly in Lyx using "Insert TeX code", bound to ALT-L by default.

So:

1. Add `\usepackage{multirow}` to your preamble (using the Document/Settings... menu item);
2. Insert [the Latex code b0lt recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863704/how-do-i-merge-cells-of-the-same-column-in-lyx/2863742#2863742).

`multirow` is part of the basic Texlive install, so you shouldn't need to import it.